# Agregar Atributo a inputs pero con misma clase

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo diversos `inputs` tipo `checkbox` con un `value ="{"valor":"1"}"` o `value ="{"valor":"0"}"`. Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" value ="{"valor":"1"}" ">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" value ="{"valor":"0"}" ">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" value ="{"valor":"0"}" ">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" value ="{"valor":"1"}" ">
```

Lo que quiero es recorrer y agregar el atributo `checked` si este es un `input` con `value {"valor":"1"}` de lo contrario no se agrega el atributo. Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" value ="{"valor":"1"}" checked">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" value ="{"valor":"0"}" ">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" value ="{"valor":"0"}" ">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch" value ="{"valor":"1"}" checked">
```

Este es mi function pero me cambia todo los inputs:

```
$('#switch').each(function(){

   if ($(this).val() == '{"valor":"1"}' )
   {
      $('#switch').attr("checked",true);
   }
   else{
     $('#switch').attr("checked",false);
   }
});
```

Se que cambia todos los inputs por que tienen el mismo id...pero ese id no lo puedo cambiar habrá otra forma de hacerlo?...

Comment: Los `id` deben ser únicos, en lo posible. Si vas a repetir tantos, te conviene usar las clases, por ejemplo: `<input class="switch" />`.

Comment: Por qué querés guardar un json `{"valor":"1"}` en el value?

Comment: La única forma que encontré es enviarle json a los valué para comprobar cuales están activo. Estos json vienen de un Array con valores 1 y 0.

Comment: Y desde donde armás eso? Porque es más sencillo armar el input con el atributo `checked` una vez que se genera que retocarlo después con javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error de concepto en el código html. por definición un id debería ser único en todo el código. No así un attr name.

Otra cosa que veo es que un checkbox no necesita value, ya que son dos estados 1, 0, prendido, apagado.

```
if( $('.micheckbox').attr('checked') ) {
    alert('Seleccionado');
}
```

Si lo que quieres es enviar al backend, usas p. ej en php `isset(controlcheckbox)` definido o no definido. p. ej. `(isset($_POST['abmt_chkactivo'])) ? 1 : 0);` (al enviar el formulario)